# Any reason to implement own authentication?

Tags: authentication

I am working on an app that will work best if connected to Apple/Google accounts (to work with photos) but does not have to. It will have login with Google/Apple/Facebook/tbd (different regions). I think I can safely ignore people who don't use any popular social services (they are not likely to be interested in my app's functionality).

Is there any point in implementing custom email/password authentication? That means database, password recovery, etc - a lot of added effort and quite some extra risk.

Personally I always prefer those social logins. They allow me to control what I share with the app, I do not have to remember a separate password, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a third party identity provider like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), then you can both provide username/password and social login through them.

Personally I often prefer username/password , as I don't want the big giants to have analytics in every thing I do. Also to keep the services more apart. Yes, social login is convenient, but at what cost?